# Id from img inserted into input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So let's say I got an image called `Feelsbadman`

And I also got an input called `#type`

Then what I want to achieve is to insert the id of my image into my input on click. 
Like this non working example:

```js
$("#Feelsbadman").click(function(){
    $("#type").val(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id = "Feelsbadman" src='https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/566c9fc265dbbdab32ec053b/1x' class = "emotes">
 <input type="text" name="message" id = "type" autocomplete="off" placeholder="type your chat message" required>
```

prefer jquery solution, but javascript is ok too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the value of the input with the id of the click handler.

```
$("#Feelsbadman").click(function(){
    $("#type").val(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot just like I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

use jquery method val() to insert value:

```
$("#Feelsbadman").click(function(){
    $("#type").val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: You don't have to do $(this) to get the id of the event

Comment: in this case, this is good too: $("#type").val('Feelsbadman');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the image tag id as value of input then use like this

```
$("#Feelsbadman").click(function(){
    $("#type").val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```